# How do I create a Javascript that finds average at every clicks on a button

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How do I create a Javascript program that find the average of numbers entered in text box every time the find button is click?

```
var all=[];
$(document).on('click', 'check', function()
{
    var second, minute, hours, aht;
    second = document.getElementById('sec').value;
    minute = document.getElementById('min').value;
    hours = document.getElementById('hour').value;
    
    nocAll.push = (eval(second + (minute * 60) + (hours * 60 *60)));
    
    for(var i =0; i< nocAll.length; i++);
    sum += parseInt(nocAll.elmt[i], 10);
    aht = sum/nocAll.length;
    
    document.getElementById("AHT").innerHTML = aht;
})
```

This shows what I have tried.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you've already tried and explain where you're having trouble. Are you stuck on how to create a click event handler, or how to do the maths?

Answer (score 0):

You edited your question so here is a way to do it.

You have a few problems in your code.

`nocAll` is **undefined** (I think you meant to use `all`

`Array.prototype.push` is a function, `all.push(value)`

```js
var all = [];
// cache the elements you will be working with
var $second = $('#sec')
var $minute = $('#min')
var $hour = $('#hour')
var $aht = $("#AHT")
// add two numbers together
var add = function(a, b) {
  return a + b
}

$(document).on('click', '.check', function() {
  // get the current values of the inputs and convert to seconds
  var hours   = Number($hour.val()) * 60 * 60
  var minutes = Number($minute.val()) * 60
  var seconds = Number($second.val())
  // add total time in seconds to the all array
  all.push(hours + minutes + seconds)
  // just for dubugging
  console.log(all)
  // calculate the average by folding the array and adding the values
  // then divide by the length
  $aht.html('average seconds:' + all.reduce(add, 0) / all.length)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="hour" placeholder="hours" />
<input type="text" id="min" placeholder="minutes" />
<input type="text" id="sec" placeholder="seconds" />
<button class="check">check</button>
<div id="AHT"></div>
```